# Maps with every point being periodic

Tags: functions, continuity, dynamical-systems

1. Does there exists a characterization of continuous maps $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ with every point $x\in [0,1]$ being periodic (i.e. if for every $x\in [0,1]$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{n}(x)=x$)?
2. What about those continuous maps $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ with every point being periodic and for which the set of all periods $\{Per(x):\ x\in [0,1]\}$ is bounded?

Comment: What do you call "periodic point" to within this context?

Comment: Do you know any such maps, other than $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=1-x$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson any “root of identity”, any $f$ such that $f^n(x)=x$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ (where $n$ is fixed) will do (note that it is not required of $f$ to be a homeomorphism).

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, what is a root of identity?

Comment: @Tomás apparently I'm being dense today; how would such function satisfy the requirement ($0,1$ appear to be the only periodic points)?

Comment: @Tomás I didn't think it was. But if $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in(0,1)$, how would we ever have $f^n(x)=x$?

Comment: @JonathanY., ops...

Comment: @Tomás a “root of identity” is a $f$ such that $f \circ f \circ \ldots f$ ($n$ times) is the identity.

Comment: I'm definitely missing something here. It appears to me that such a function would have to be injective. Hence it would have to be monotonic (continuous bijection). Hence it would have to be one of the functions @GerryMyerson mentioned. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice question.

I'll answer your second question first. If all periods are bounded by $N$, then $f^{N!}$ is the identity. Thus $f$ is a homeomorphism, as $f^{N!-1}$ is an inverse. In particular $f$ must be monotonic.

EDIT: In fact, this holds under the hypotheses of question 1 as well. If $f^n(x)=x$ and $f^m(y)=y$ then $f^{mn}(x)=x$ and $f^{mn}(y)=y$. In particular $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$. Thus $f$ is injective, so it must be monotonic. Thanks to @JonathanY. for this observation.

Suppose that $f$ is monotonically increasing, and suppose there is some $x$ such that $f(x)\neq x$. If $f(x)>x$ then $f^n(x)>x$ for all $n$. Similarly if $f(x)<x$ then $f^n(x)<x$ for all $x$. Thus we must have $f(x)=x$ for all $x$.

If on the other hand $f$ is monotonically decreasing then $f^2$ is monotonically increasing, so we must have $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x$. There are many such functions, but they all have this form: take any $0<\omega<1$ and any decreasing homeomorphism $g:[0,\omega]\to[\omega,1]$ and define (with obvious notation) $f=g\cup g^{-1}$.

EDIT: Every such $f$ is "homeomorphically-conjugate" to $1-x$, in the sense that there exists a homeomorphism $h:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that $hfh^{-1}(x)=1-x$. One such $h$ is
$$
 h(x) =
 \begin{cases}
   \frac{x}{2\omega} & \text{if $x\leq\omega$,}\\
   1 - \frac{f(x)}{2\omega} & \text{if $x\geq\omega$.}
 \end{cases}
$$
Indeed, then $h(f(x))=1-h(x)$. Thank you to @GerryMyerson for this observation.

[Old Baire argument, now defunct:
Now for your first question. Let $X$ be the set of all $x\in[0,1]$ for which there does not exist an integer $n$ and an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f^n(y)=y$ for all $y\in U$. Clearly $X$ is closed, so it is a complete metric space. Let $E_n$ be the set of all $x\in X$ such that $f^n(x)=x$. Then each $E_n$ is closed in $X$, and $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$. If $X\neq\emptyset$, the Baire category theorem implies that some $E_n$ has nonempty interior, which leads straight to a contradiction. Thus $X=\emptyset$, and so by compactness of $[0,1]$ there must exist $N$ such that $f^N(x)=x$ for all $x$.]

Comment: The proof in the final paragraph above is almost identical to the proof of this assertion: If $f$ is a smooth function $\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ such that for every $x$ there is some $n$ such that the $n$th derivative $f^{(n)}$ vanishes at $x$, then $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: SeanEberhard, since $[0,1]$ is compact, isn't every continuous bijection a homeomorphism? In short, isn't every function with all of $[0,1]$ for periodic points monotonic?

Comment: @JonathanY. My answers shows yes, but I don't think it's completely trivial, is it? It's obvious that such a function $f$ must be surjective, but is it obvious that it must be injective as well?

Comment: It seems you're right: If $f^n(x)=x$ and $f^m(y)=y$ then $f^{mn}(x)=x$ and $f^{mn}(y)=y$. In particular $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$. This simplifies the answer considerably.

Comment: Oh good, this question made me doubt everything I was thinking ;)

Comment: Just to give a completely explicit example, every $x$ is periodic of period 2 for $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, except for the one fixed point, $x=\sqrt{1/2}$.

Comment: One little question: I don't get the point that $f$ is homeomorphism. Was it meant to be or it was particular case? As far as I understand, original question was asking about only continuous mappings of segment.

Comment: @Evgeny The hypotheses imply that $f$ is injective and surjective. Therefore $f$ must be a homeomorphism. (Recall: A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space must be a homeomorphism.)